# Difference Boolean causes problem with smooth shading

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I've only recently started using blender and have been using the difference Boolean quite a bit. Most of the time there are no problems, however when trying to create a hole in a phone model I'm working on the result in smooth shading is a massive dark shape across the object. This does not appear when using flat shading.

Like I said, I'm new to blender so any help would be appreciated! I've looked through forums and videos but have found no answer.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use booleans, use [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com) instead

Comment: try adding edge split modifier

Comment: Thanks! The Edge Split Modifier seems to have worked perfectly.